# How to test file uploads to an API using Mockery and PHPUnit

Tags: unit-testing, symfony, laravel, phpunit, mockery

I'm using PHPUnit to test my API but I'm unsure as to how to test file uploads.

I watched [this Laracast lesson](https://laracasts.com/series/build-project-flyer-with-me/episodes/17) which has given me a good insight into how to use Mockery to mock the uploads, but in my case I'm trying to test an API and, for whatever reason, I can't get my test to Green.

**My test code:**

```
namespace App;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use Mockery as m;

class ApiResourcesControllerTest extends \TestCase
{
    /** @test */
    function a_user_can_upload_a_resource()
    {
        $file = m::mock(UploadedFile::class, [
            'getClientOriginalName' => 'test.jpg'
        ]);

        $file->shouldReceive('move') // the uploaded file is moved 
             ->once()
             ->with('uploads', 'now-test.jpg');

        $files = ['file' => $file]; // endpoint expects Input::file('file);

        // this endpoint definitely works
        $this->call('POST', 'api/resources/upload', [], [], $files);
        $this->dump(); // for the mean time just dump the response
    }
}

function time()
{
    return 'now';
}
```

I know that the `api/resources/upload` endpoint works just fine, but my test code returns the following error:

```
Mockery\Exception\InvalidCountException: Method move("uploads", "now-test.jpg") from Mockery_0_Symfony_Component_HttpFoundation_File_UploadedFile should be called exactly 1 times but called 0 times.
```

Where am I going wrong?

Examples of mocking file uploads to an API would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi. If you delete '->once()' you will have error?